# Keep paint within image boundaries

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paint

I am building a kid's Paint application for iPad. Basically I have made a canvas which has an image and, using Mouse Event, one can color on it. However, I do not want the color to get outside of the boundaries of my image. How is that possible?

My app code is quite similar to [this sample code](http://cool-php-tutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/simple-html5-drawing-app-with-saving.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Solution 1: Well i got this working by first making the image background white and inner part transparent followed by setting globalcompositeoperation as destination-atop.

2) Solution 2: I have placed the image on top of the canvas element using css and then used a css property called pointer-events:none. This makes the event pass through the object in the front onto the behind element, which in this case is my canvas. So due to the inner transparent part of the image, you can see the color on the canvas and as the image background is white, you cant see anything behind it.

Answer (score 1):

When I understood you correctly, you want the user to be unable to destroy the lineart of the template image.

You could place the lineart image on another HTML element (you could use another canvas, but a static img would likely be sufficient) and place this one over the canvas the user draws on using CSS positioning. The paint-canvas below will be seen through the transparent parts of the image above.

Note that the input events will then be caught by the upper object, not the lower one.

Comment: nice idea..but the problem is i am new to canvas and javascript and my knowledge is not that advanced as of know. can you show me a working solution? it would be a great help..thanks